# Apply character set in regex lookbehind

Tags: regex

I need to get the subnets count of bgp 7029, using regexp like

```
(?<=bgp 7029[\s]+\d[\s+])\d
```

but this doesn't work with positive look behind.

```
sh ip route vrf vrf-dnoc-mpls-test summary
IP routing table name is vrf-dnoc-mpls-test (0x2)
IP routing table maximum-paths is 32
Route Source    Networks    Subnets     Replicates  Overhead    Memory (bytes)
static          0           0           0           0           0
connected       0           1           0           60          172
bgp 7029        0           1686        0           101160      289992
  External: 0 Internal: 1686 Local: 0
internal        36                                              73652
Total           36          1687        0           101220      363816
```

Comment: Most regexp engines require lookbehind to have a fixed size, you can't use quantifiers like `+`.

Comment: Do you really need to use `+`? Isn't the number of spaces always the same?

Comment: Please specify which regex engine you are using (typically, in which programming language).

Comment: From the [regex tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info): "Since regular expressions are not fully standardized, all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool."

Comment: I'm using this regex in Groovy language

Answer (score 1):

Don't really need a lookbehind, a capture group will work just as well.

`bgp[ \t]7029[ \t]+\d+[ \t]+(\d+)`

where the subnet is in group 1